# Div keeps bouncing

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I want a div (return to top) to appear if the user scrolls down and the menu disappears. The div slides down and bounces but it keeps bouncing. I only want it to bounce once, before it's set to position fixed.

I understand that this happens because the code runs over and over again as long as "(distance + navHeight) <= 1", but is there a way to just run the code once?

```
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    var scrollTop     = $(window).scrollTop(),
        elementOffset = $('.navigation').offset().top,
        navHeight = $('.navigation').height();
        distance      = Math.round((elementOffset - scrollTop));

    if((distance + navHeight) <= 1) {
        $('#scroll-top').slideToggle(700, 'easeOutBounce', function() {
            $(this).addClass('menu-stick');
        });
    }
});
```

CSS

```
.menu-stick {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2000;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

EDIT: [Here is the live version](http://henrikpetersson.se/perfectsquare/)

Comment: Can you post your HTML and a fiddle as well?

Comment: Everytime you scroll and the condition `(distance + navHeight) <= 1` is true, the slideToggle event will fire which, subsequently, fires the bounce easing animation.  I assume the bouncing stops when not scrolling, correct?

Comment: @MikeHometchko: Actually it keeps bouncing even if I stop scroll. You can check it out a live version (linked at the bottom of the question).

Comment: there is jQuerys one function, but I don't believe that can be used with your particular scroll event, as the first scroll would do nothing and then your code would not run after that.

Comment: Does it bounce indefinitely?  You are activating that event for every pixel scrolled (I think it's every pixel) so it may just be the event firing like 4k times.

Comment: I see you fixed the problem with @JohnRooney's answer but I have to suggest moving the class check outside of the initial `(distance + navHeight) <= 1` to eliminate the unnecessary calculation everytime you scroll.  Better yet, create a global flag to toggle when the class is added/removed.  With your site the performance gain will be negligible but it's good practice.

Answer (score 2):

Change the action's trigger selector to `#scroll-top:not(.menu-stick)`

So:

```
if (distance + navHeight) <= 1) {
    $('#scroll-top:not(.menu-stick)').slideToggle(700, 'easeOutBounce', function() {
        $(this).addClass('menu-stick');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I obviously can't see all of your code, but possibly try doing a check if the element is already stuck or not:

```
if ( !$('#scroll-top').hasClass('menu-stick') ) {
    // Do animation
    // add class 'menu-stick'
}
```